# Cannot run XCTests

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So, I was testing, then I probably did something to mess Xcode up because now no tests will appear:

[image: 0 tests? But I have a test right there!]

I can, however, run the target and it will correctly run the tests (in this case testSignup).

Any idea how I can enable it again? I've tried clearing derived data, quitting Xcode, cleaning and restarting.

Comment: Yes, there *are* bugs in Xcode... :)

Comment: Have changed name of project or Name of executable file?

Answer (score 0):

What I do when tests get messed up (which happens quite often, actually) is to delete the test target and make a new test target. If you have any tests you've already written, copy them first!